# Agrupando dados por período

Tags: sql-server

Estou fazendo uma consulta no banco, para retornar a entrada de produtos por hora (de 00:00 até 23:00) durante um determinado dia; segue a consulta:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(13),DATA_ENTRADA,120)+ ':00:00' AS HORA,COUNT(*) AS QTD 
  FROM Tb_Produtos 
  GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(13),DATA_ENTRADA,120)+ ':00:00' 
  ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(13),DATA_ENTRADA,120)+ ':00:00';
```

Essa consulta me mostra só as quantidades nos horários que eu tenho registro; segue o retorno:

```
HORA                 /  QTD

2017-01-01 00:00:00  /  4
2017-01-01 06:00:00  /  2
2017-01-01 07:00:00  /  2
2017-01-01 08:00:00  /  3
2017-01-01 10:00:00  /  1
2017-01-01 12:00:00  /  22
2017-01-01 13:00:00  /  24
2017-01-01 14:00:00  /  43
2017-01-01 15:00:00  /  22
2017-01-01 16:00:00  /  27
2017-01-01 17:00:00  /  18
2017-01-01 18:00:00  /  17
2017-01-01 19:00:00  /  23
2017-01-01 20:00:00  /  28
2017-01-01 21:00:00  /  46
2017-01-01 22:00:00  /  18
2017-01-01 23:00:00  /  10
```

É possível retornar uma quantidade 0 no horário em que não possuir nenhum registro?

Ex:
    HORA                 /  QTD

```
2017-01-01 00:00:00  /  4
2017-01-01 01:00:00  /  0
2017-01-01 02:00:00  /  0
2017-01-01 03:00:00   / 0
2017-01-01 04:00:00   / 0
2017-01-01 05:00:00  /  0
2017-01-01 06:00:00  /  2
2017-01-01 07:00:00  /  2
2017-01-01 08:00:00 /   3
2017-01-01 10:00:00 /   1
2017-01-01 11:00:00  /  0
2017-01-01 12:00:00  /  22
2017-01-01 13:00:00 /   24
2017-01-01 14:00:00  /  43
2017-01-01 15:00:00 /   22
2017-01-01 16:00:00  /  27
2017-01-01 17:00:00  /  18
2017-01-01 18:00:00  /  17
2017-01-01 19:00:00  /  23
2017-01-01 20:00:00 /   28
2017-01-01 21:00:00  /  46
2017-01-01 22:00:00 /   18
2017-01-01 23:00:00 /   10
```

Desde já agradeço

Comment: A produção deve ser contabilizada por dia/hora ou somente por hora?

Comment: Poderia criar a estrutura da tabela e os insert, para a gente tentar ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Avalie a seguinte sugestão, que contabiliza a produção por dia/hora:

```
-- código #1 v2
-- informa o período de emissão (formato dd/mm/aaaa)
declare @dataInicial datetime, @dataFinal datetime;
set @dataInicial= convert(datetime, '1/1/2017', 103);
set @dataFinal= convert(datetime, '1/1/2017', 103);

-- ajusta horário da data final (23:59:59.997)
set @dataFinal= dateadd(ms, -3, dateadd(day, +1, @dataFinal));

--
with 
-- cria tabela completa de horários para o período de emissão
cteHoraDia as (
SELECT @dataInicial as horaBásica
union all
SELECT DateAdd(hour, +1, horaBásica)
  from cteHoraDia
  where horaBásica < dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, @dataFinal), 0)
),
-- contabiliza a produção por dia/hora
cteProdHora as (
SELECT horaProd= dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, DATA_ENTRADA), 0),
       Count(*) as Qtd
  from Tb_Produtos
  where DATA_ENTRADA between @dataInicial and @dataFinal
  group by dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, DATA_ENTRADA), 0)
)
--
SELECT T1.horaBásica as Horário, IsNull(T2.Qtd, 0) as Qtd
  from cteHoraDia as T1
       left join cteProdHora as T2 on T2.horaProd = T1.horaBásica;
go
```

No primeiro passo do código informa-se o período de emissão do relatório; deve-se informar somente os dias, sem horários.

O segundo passo é criar uma lista completa de horários, abrangendo o período de emissão. Isso ocorre na CTE cteHoraDia.

O terceiro passo é contabilizar a produção de cada dia/hora. Isso é feito na CTE cteProdHora. Observe que foi utilizada forma (teoricamente) mais eficiente de converter o horário hh:mm:ss em hh:00:00.

Finalmente, a lista completa de horários é emitida, acrescentando a contabilização de produção para dia/hora, quando existir.

---

*José Diz*     Belo Horizonte, MG - Brasil

Comment: Muito Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente.